# ASP.net URL rewrite based off query string ID

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Hey everyone I am trying to figure out how to re write a url such as www.mywebsit.com/Articles/newsInfo.aspx?id=3 to www.mywebisite.com/Articles/My-News-Title.aspx

I don't know if I am misunderstanding something but below is the code i have and nothing seems to be happening. The URL stays the same.

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim currPath As String = Request.Url.ToString

    If currPath.IndexOf("Articles") <> -1 And currPath.IndexOf("?np=") <> -1 Then
        currPath = currPath.Substring(currPath.IndexOf("?np=") + 4)
        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConString").ConnectionString
        Dim myreader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Using myConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Try
                myConnection.Open()
                Dim myCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()


                myCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TheNewsTitle FROM TheNews WHERE TheNewsId=" & currPath.Replace("'", "''")
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection

                myreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
                If myreader.HasRows Then
                    myreader.Read()
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/Articles/" & myreader.GetValue(0).ToString.Replace(" ", "-") & ".aspx")
                    myreader.Close()

                End If

                myConnection.Close()
                myCommand.Dispose()
                myConnection.Dispose()

            Catch ex As Exception
                myConnection.Close()
                myConnection.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

The code never errors out so i don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do actual URL Rewriting ? In other words - you want the links in your site to look like

> www.mywebsite.com/Articles/My-News-Title.aspx

and be processed by

> www.mywebsite.com/Articles/newsInfo.aspx?id=3

yes ?

Have a look here: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: These got me pointed in the right direction. It took me a while to get my head wrapped around a few concepts. Thanks a bunch!