# ASP.NET/UpdatePanel/URL Rewriete "Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check."

Tags: asp.net, iis, updatepanel, viewstate, url-rewrite-module

We are using and update panel with a repeater inside on url "/casestudy/":

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LoadMore" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">                 
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <%# Eval("Title") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
                <div class="row center">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="$(this).hide();" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" ID="LoadMore" Text="VIEW MORE" />                                  
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

We also rewrite the url "location/case-study" to this same page using this outbound rule:

```
<rule name="test" preCondition="IsHTML" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
      <match filterByTags="A" pattern="(.*)" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/{C:1}{R:0}" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{R:0}" pattern="(location|this|that)" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="IsHTML">
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
```

The repeater works great when the outbound rewrite is not applied but we receive "Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check" on the page after the outbound rule is applied.

I have tried restricting axd files from the outbound rule, setting enableviewstatemac to false, changing the form action and setting the machine key. What am I missing? I read that the out bound rules are not applied to updatepanel content, but if so how do I fix?

I appreciate anyone's help and suggestions.

Comment: Do you have to rewrite URL's this way ? You could use page routing instead, which can be used in a webforms app. I have never had any problems with that combination.

Comment: the visible URL needs to have "location" preceding per business rules. The word location in the URL could be replaced with locations/city names for franchises.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here - [ASP.net URL rewrite based off query string ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033300/asp-net-url-rewrite-based-off-query-string-id/21033395#21033395)

I think your scenario can be handled using page routing.

Comment: We use the outbound rule to rewrite visible links on the page. Does routing allow for outbound rewriting?